# select text underneath header in jquery

Tags: jquery, cheerio

I'm looking a way to dynamically select a text block located underneath a header.

So far I've tried to do that using `$('#importantHeader').next()` and `$('#importantHeader').next('p')`
but it doesn't work in all situations.

For example, if the header is wrapped in a `<div>` or any other element, the `.next()`-Method doesn't work because it returns `undefined`.

Now I'm looking for a way that works whether the header and text block are wrapped inside other elements or not, regardless of the DOM structure.

Like saying "select whatever text block the page displays right underneath this specific header"

Here are some HTML-examples the solution needs to work with:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <p>this is some random text I DON'T want to select</p>
    </div>
    <h4 id="importantHeader">This is the header I selected</h4>
    <div>
        <p>This is the text I want to select</p>
    </div>
    <h4 id="randomHeader">This is a header for the next section</h4>
    <div>
        <p>This is some random text I DON'T want to select</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

_

```
<p>this is some random text I DON'T want to select</p>
<h4 id="importantHeader">This is the header I selected</h4>
<div>This is the text I want to select</div>
<h4 id="randomHeader">header for next section</h4>
<p>This is some random text I DON'T want to select</p>
```

_

```
<div>
    <p>this is some random text I DON'T want to select</p>
</div>
<div><div><div>
    <h4 id="importantHeader">This is the header I selected</h4>
</div></div></div>
<div><div>
    <p>This is the text I want to select</p>
</div></div>
<div>
    <h4 id="randomHeader">header for next section</h4>
    <p>This is some random text I DON'T want to select</p>
</div>
```

Is there any possibility to do this in jQuery or Cheerio?

Comment: Can you define "Selecting" the header? You mean just highlight it or select by clicking on it or selecting a checkbox?

Comment: @Alwaysa Beginner I mean that i use the header to determine what text block should be selected.

Comment: Ah! I get it now... In that case, if you are not sure how is the DOM structure goiing to be or what is going to be the relative position of <p> to importantHeader, then my opinion is that it's best to assign an ID to the <p> as well  
`<p id="importantDisplay">Text to be selected</p>`

Comment: @AlwaysaBeginner That's a good idea. Is something like this also possible when you don't know whether the text block is going to be inside a <p>? problem is that it I need it to generally work on text nodes, even when the text is not inside a <p> and without me knowing the ID ..

It's a web scraping use case where the pages are differently structured. I can rely on always being able to select the right header with jquery, but the header's corresponding text block that follows right after can be buried under all kinds of other html tags..

Comment: Sorry but I cannot think of any way this can be done....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a working solution that works with cheerio's `.next()`.

As @IRLotsEvil mentioned, `.next()` can only select a sibling. So I can simply create a loop with a running variable going through the parent elements, until it has a sibling which contains text nodes.

```
let rv = $(myHeader); // running variable
while(rv.next().text().trim() === '') {
    rv = rv.parent();
}
let sectionContent = rv.next().text().trim();
```

I didn't expect it to be that simple, but so far, it gets the job done without errors :)

Answer (score 1):

`next` is a function designed for selecting siblings so 'p' is not a sibling of '#importantHeader' whereas 'div' is.

If you're trying to select `Text` nodes then i'm not entirely sure how JQuery would select them, however this is what it would kind of look like in vanilla JS:

```
    // Select all elements from within the Body element (change the query to the container of the elements you want)
    var allTheTextNodes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("body *")).
        // filter each element's childNodes to ensure they are Text nodes and make sure the text isn't empty
        map(x=>Array.from(x.childNodes).filter(y=>y instanceof Text && y.nodeValue.replace(/[\r\t\n\s]/g,"") !== "")).
        // filter out any elements that didn't have any Text nodes and combine all the arrays together  
        filter(x=>x.length>0).reduce((a,c)=>a.concat(c),[]);
    
    console.log(allTheTextNodes);
```

Then you could filter based on the parent/ancestors of said `Text` node if you wanted.
However this can get pretty weighty the more elements there are in the document.
I'm not sure if this is the kind of thing you were looking for.

Comment: I think this could actually help me find the solution. Is there a way to determine which one of 'allTheTextNodes' comes first after a specific header? So that I can select the "next text node after that header"